# Actions not triggering subsequent actions

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, angular-ngrx-data

[Github link](https://github.com/rootrepo/angular-store-example) to my sample program.

in file **app.component.ts** created a session expiry action which will be triggered once timeout happens

```
 timerExpiration : setTimeout(() => {
          this.store.dispatch(SessionActions.expirationTimerElapsed())
        }, 2000) as unknown as number  ,
```

once above action

in effect of `SessionActions.expirationTimerElapsed` is completed,

`SessionActions.terminateSession`
action should be triggered

**session.effects.ts**

```
expiredTimer = createEffect(()=> 
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(SessionActions.expirationTimerElapsed),
      map(()=> SessionActions.terminateSession({reason :'TimeOut'}))
    )
  );
```

but SessionActions.terminateSession is not called.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your repo doesn't have `ngrx` as dependecy... `npm install` doesn't install ngrx....

Comment: @Andres2142 installed manually for my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect needs to be registered in a module.
For more info see the docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects

Comment: missed it .. thanks